# Crop and merge PDF files

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-editor

I wish to edit PDF pages, crop them and merge the newly obtained pages into a PDF.

Which software (preferably free) would be the best for this?

I've heard of Adobe Pagemaker, but I was wondering if there are any alternatives.

I'm using Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[PDFsam](https://pdfsam.org/)** is a free app to merge pages of PDF files. I've used it and it works great and is very fast.
It is available from Sourceforge and comes as a ready to run app.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://en.pdf24.org/. Lets you easily merge PDFs. Pages can be rearranged as you wish. Better interface than PDFSam.

Comment: While I like the pdf24 software which has this clause in it "1.1.5 The PDF24 Creator is provided only for the use and distribution in the area of the European Union."  Which excludes many.

Answer (score 1):

PDFArranger.
https://github.com/pdfarranger/pdfarranger

Apart from their crazy menu (What is wrong with "File > Open"?), it is an excellent tool.

It does exactly what you are looking for, and it feels really nice.

[image]

[image]